# PHP on IIS get the current rewritten URL

Tags: php, iis

Is there anyway of getting the current full rewritten URL in PHP on IIS.

For instance, I have a URL like:

http://www.domain.com/searchresults.php?section=99&page=1&model=section-name

which is rewritten to:
http://www.domain.com/section99/page1/section-name

I've been able to piece together the original URL using :

```
function selfURL(){
    if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
        $serverrequri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }else{
        $serverrequri =    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";
    $protocol = "http";
    $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
    return $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$serverrequri.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];   
}
print(selfURL());
```

Is there anyway I can easily pick the rewritten URL to avoid the overhead of having to work out the friendly URL from a number of different formats and variables depending on the current page type?

Comment: Are you using ISAPI_Rewrite for IIS?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Getting the rewritten URL for a non rewrite URL? Why? Why don't you just work with the rewritten URL all the time?

Comment: No. We're on IIS7 and using the built in rewrite module

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. Work with the rewritten URL. I am trying to grab this. My issue is that I can only get the original URL not the rewritten one

Comment: I would recommend you to work with the [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) rules of Apache in a `.htaccess` file and then importing them to IIS 7. Which will generate the `web.config` file.

Comment: I've got it. Answer below

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to work with the [mod_rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) of Apache in a `.htaccess` file and then importing them to IIS 7. Which will generate the web.config file.

Of course, if you know how to work directly on the `web.config`, go for it!

Answer (score 0):

I can use:

**HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL**

```
function selfURL(){
    if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
        $serverrequri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }else{
        $serverrequri =    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    $protocol = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? 'http' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https" : "http";
    $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
    return $protocol."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$port.$_SERVER["HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL"];
}
print(selfURL());
```